# How to go all element with same class in page name using selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I have a page opened in selenium VBA, and on this page I have a lot of elements with the same class name,  So, how i can update the inputs" element by element using a for a loop until it reaches the element

```html
<div class="jss10">
<div class="jss11">
<label class="jss16">Auction Name</label><span class="jss13">*</span>
<div class="jss12"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" title="Auction name" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; color: gray;"><path d="M11 7h2v2h-2zm0 4h2v6h-2zm1-9C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"></path></svg></div></div><div class="jss14"><div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root"><div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-formControl"><input aria-invalid="false" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" value=""><fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss17 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline" style="padding-left: 8px;"><legend class="jss18" style="width: 0.01px;"><span>​</span></legend></fieldset></div></div></div></div>

<div class="jss10">
<div class="jss11">
<label class="jss16">Invited Suppliers</label>
<span class="jss13">*</span>
<div class="jss12"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" title="Total suppliers invited for the Auction" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; color: gray;"><path d="M11 7h2v2h-2zm0 4h2v6h-2zm1-9C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"></path></svg></div></div><div class="jss14"><div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root"><div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-formControl"><input aria-invalid="false" type="number" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" value=""><fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss17 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline" style="padding-left: 8px;"><legend class="jss18" style="width: 0.01px;"><span>​</span></legend></fieldset></div></div></div></div>

<div class="jss10">
<div class="jss11">
<label class="jss16">Sellers Without Initial Bid</label>
<span class="jss13">*</span>
<div class="jss12"><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; color: gray;"><path d="M11 7h2v2h-2zm0 4h2v6h-2zm1-9C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8z"></path></svg></div></div><div class="jss14"><div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root"><div class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-formControl"><input aria-invalid="false" type="number" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input" value=""><fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss17 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline" style="padding-left: 8px;"><legend class="jss18" style="width: 0.01px;"><span>​</span></legend></fieldset></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Two of those inputs are listbox controls. Do you intend to interact with them? They only show numeric values at present.

Comment: Yes it is required